# postgresql does not recognize variable name introduced in WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm getting an error in my user-defined-function, and to an extent, I understand the error (unrecognized column), but not why it's being caused. Here is the minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
create table foo (id serial primary key, name varchar not null);

create table bar (id serial primary key, name varchar not null);

create function foo_to_bar(foo_id int) returns void as $$
begin
    with _name as (
        select name from foo where id = foo_id
    )
    insert into bar (name) values (_name);
                    -- error here: ~~~~~
end;

$$ language plpgsql;

insert into foo (name) values ('slimshady');
-- id of first entry will be 1

select foo_to_bar(1);
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "_name" does not exist
LINE 4:     insert into bar (name) values (_name)
                                           ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "bar.name".
QUERY:  with _name as (
        select name from foo where id = foo_id
    )
    insert into bar (name) values (_name)
```

Why is it totally ignoring the `_name` that I created in the `with` clause, three line above where the error is being raised? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_name` is not a variable, it's a derived table name, so your statement should look like

```
with _name as (
    select name from foo where id = foo_id
)
insert into bar (name) select name from _name;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: If I had other function arguments that need to be inserted into `bar`, how would I add them to the `insert` statement?

Comment: Got it! `insert into bar (name, otherfield) select name, _otherfield from _name`, where _otherfield is an additional argument to the function